# Do I need the conjunction "and" in this sentence

Tags: conjunctions

Consider:

> The MD simulations were performed at three different temperatures (298, 323, and 348 K) **and at the atmospheric pressure**.

Is it better to remove the **and**

> The MD simulations were performed at three different temperatures (298, 323, and 348 K), **at the atmospheric pressure**.

or

> The MD simulations were performed at three different temperatures (298, 323, and 348 K), **all at the atmospheric pressure**.

Comment: no **and**, and no **the**:  ... *at atmospheric pressure*.

Comment: @TRomano isn't atmospheric pressure an specific pressure?

Comment: The pressure is a specific pressure: it is *atmospheric* pressure.  It is analogous to "room temperature" in "Let the dough sit overnight in a covered bowl at room temperature".

Comment: Compare also "civic duty".   It is a specific duty: *civic* duty. *The magazine article was about civic duty.*

Comment: The adjective functions as a determiner.

Comment: @TRomano it is a specific pressure but not a particular isolated one to be point at, right?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @TRomano I mean when I would use "**the** atmospheric pressure"?, I guessed it must be a single isolated.... pressure so that I can point at... to use "the"....

Comment: To refer to a specific atmospheric pressure, you would use **an** instead of **the**: "... at an atmospheric pressure of 2 bars." To distinguish atmospheric pressure from another kind of pressure, you could say "I am referring to **the** atmospheric pressure";  **the** would be allowed there but not required.